# Use dplyr to compute proportional change

Tags: r, dplyr

My data frame consists of three columns: state name, year, and the tax receipt for each year and each state. Below is an example for just one state.

```
  year RealTaxRevs
1 1971     8335046
2 1972     9624026
3 1973    10498935
4 1974    10052305
5 1975     8708381
6 1976     8911262
7 1977    10759032
```

I'd like to compute the changes in terms of percentage of the previous year tax receipt (e.g. (1977 tax receipt - 1976 tax receipt) / 1976 tax receipt). The code probably looks like this:

```
data %>% group_by(state) %>% mutate(change = c(NA, diff(RealTaxRevs)/RealTaxRevs
```

But it doesn't work because it's computing the percentages with respect to THIS year tax receipt. How do I shift RealTaxRevs backward by one position so that I can compute the percentage with respect to the previous year tax receipt? Or an elegant way to that in dplyr?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  mutate(change = RealTaxRevs / lag(RealTaxRevs) - 1)
```

Comment: that looks great but why the -1?

Comment: Because `(a - b) / b = (a / b - 1)`

Comment: Ah I see. Is the form you use more numerically stable?

Comment: It could be more efficient (calling lag only once).